# How to fix Vector Position within Struct Player object so it'll work with me.position in Main?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am teaching myself C++11 and this was one of my homework assignment, however the vector position; doesn't seem to work.

I've tried #include  and std::vector, nothing seems to work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


struct Player
{
    string name;
    int hp;
    vector position;
}; 

int main()
{
   Player me;
   me.name = "Metalogic";
   me.hp = 100;
   me.position.x = me.position.y = me.position.z = 0;

   return 0;
}
```

I'd like for it to `cout << player << hp << position`

Comment: `std::vector` is a dynamic array, not a 3D vector. It doesn't have a `x`, `y` or `z` member

Comment: What about to define a  `struct Position` to manage the position ? that allows to add methods on it rather than to have a 'general' _vector_  used to memorize coordinates. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried #include and std::vector, nothing seems to work.

Your way to use the *vector* is wrong, you have to write in entries specifying index or to `push_back(..)` etc.

So of course you can  use a vector having 3 entries for memorizing x,y and z but what about to define a *struct Position* to be able to add additional behaviors on it (*move* etc) ?

```
struct Position {
  int x;
  int y;
  int z;
}

struct Player
{
    string name;
    int hp;
    Position position;
}; 

int main()
{
   Player me;
   me.name = "Metalogic";
   me.hp = 100;
   me.position.x = me.position.y = me.position.z = 0;

   return 0;
}
```

Note you can also have a default constructor initializing the x, y and z to 0 to not have to do each time

```
struct Position {
  Position() : x(0), y(0), z(0) {}
  int x;
  int y;
  int z;
}

struct Player
{
    string name;
    int hp;
    Position position;
}; 

int main()
{
   Player me;
   me.name = "Metalogic";
   me.hp = 100;

   return 0;
}
```

> I'd like for it to cout << player << hp << position

*hp* and *position* are part of *Player* so `std::cout << player` is enough

Just adding the `operator<<`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Position {
  Position() : x(0), y(0), z(0) {}

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Position & p) {
     os << "[" << p.x << ' ' << p.y << ' ' << p.z << ']';
     return os;
  }
  int x;
  int y;
  int z;
};

struct Player
{
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Player & p) {
       os << p.name << ' ' << p.hp << ' ' << p.position;
       return os;
    }
    std::string name;
    int hp;
    Position position;
}; 

int main()
{
   Player me;
   me.name = "Metalogic";
   me.hp = 100;
   me.position.x = 123; // y and z use default value 0

   std::cout << me << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wextra -Wall p.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Metalogic 100 [123 0 0]
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: OP also needs to overload `operator<<` since they state they want `cout << player << hp << position` to work

Comment: @UnholySheep ah yes I didn't see. I edited my answer, thank you for the remark

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Vector3D
{
    int x, y, z;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, Vector3D const &position)
{
    return os << '[' << position.x << ", " << position.y << ", " << position.z << ']';
}

struct Player
{
    std::string name;
    int hp;
    Vector3D position;
}; 

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, Player const &player)
{
    return os << '\"' << player.name << "\" (" << player.hp << ") " << player.position;
}

int main()
{
    Player me{ "Metalogic", 100, {} };
    std::cout << me << '\n';

    Player you{ "Luigi", 900, { 1, 2, 3 } };
    std::cout << you << '\n';
}
```